# Query too large (over 16k characters) to safely obfuscate using IN (IDs)

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to rewrite this a query that I have on my system where the IN (IDs) is crossing the limits.

To contextualize a little about this part of the system, I have a register of service groups and in this register I specify which users serve certain customers, the problem is that there are companies that have 6k+ registered customers and of these 6k they select 5k to be part of of a group.

I'm using IN to make this query, when there are few customers there is no problem, the big problem is when there are many customers linked to the service group.

the system follows the following structure:

I have a model called Company, this model is used for both companies and clients:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :companies
  belongs_to :company

  has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :service_groups, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :service_group_companies, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My other model is Orders, where the companies are linked by the company_id column and the customers by the customer_id column, that is, an order is linked to a company and a customer of that company.

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :company
 belongs_to :customer, class_name: 'Company', foreign_key: :customer_id
 belongs_to :user
end
```

Model Users:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :order
  has_many :service_group_users, dependent: :destroy
end
```

And service group models:

```
class ServiceGroup < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  has_many :service_group_companies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :service_group_users, dependent: :destroy
end
class ServiceGroupCompany < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service_group
  belongs_to :company
end
class ServiceGroupUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :service_group
  belongs_to :user
end
```

today I am writing the query as follows:

```
group_user = user.service_group_users.last

group = group_user.service_group
customer_ids  = group.service_group_companies.select(:company_id).collect(&:company_id)
    
company.orders.where('orders.customer_id IN (:customer_ids)')
```

I needed this query to be rewritten in a way that makes it lighter, not to burst the limit, if anyone can help me I'm very grateful.

Comment: Remove `.collect(&:company_id)` and change the last line to `company.orders.where(orders: {customer_id: customer_ids})`. This will create a subquery and resolve the issue

Comment: Even better, use a join.